# C++ punctuation

Tags: c++, punctuation

More social curiosity than actual programming question...

A thousand years ago when I took my first programming class (Fortran 66) and a mere 500 years ago when I tokk my first C and C++ classes, there were some pretty standard punctuation practices across languages.  I saw them in Basic (shudder), PL/1, PL/AS, Rexx even Pascal.  Ok, APL2 is not part of this discussion.

Each language has its own peculiar punctuation.  Pascal's periods, Fortran's comma separated do loops, almost everybody else's semicolons.

As I learned it, each language also has KEYWORDS (if, for, do, while, until, etc.) which are set off by whitespace (or the left margin) <space>if<space>, etc.

Each language has function, subroutines of whatever they're called.  Some built-in some user coded.  They were set off by <whitespace|left margin>function_name( parameters );.  As in sqrt( x ) or rand( y );

Lately, there seems to be a new set of punctuation rules.  Especially in c++ where initializers get glued onto the end of variable declarations   int  x(0); or auto_ptr<p> p(new gizmo);  This invariably fools me into thinking someone is declaring a function prototoye or using a function as a integer (huh?).

Then "if" and 'for' seems to have grown parens; if(true)  for(;;), etc.  Since when did keywords become functions.

And finally, functions seem to have shed their parens;  sqrt (2)  select (...)

Question:  when did the old ways disappear and this new way come into vogue?  Does anyone besides me find it irritating to read and that the information that the placement of punctuation used to convey is gone?  I know full well that K&R put the { at the end of the "if" or "for" to save a byte here and there.  Can't use that excuse here.  Space as an excuse for loss of readability died as HDD space soared past 100 MiB.

Your thoughts are solicited.  If there is a good reason to do this, I'll gladly learn it and maybe in another 50 years I'll get used to it.  Of course it's good that compilers recognize these (IMHO) typos and keep right on going, but just because you CAN code it that way doesn't mean you HAVE to, right?

Thanks!

Comment: This belongs on programmers.SE

Comment: IMHO, as long as your code follows basic standards, has descriptive variable names and nice clean neat code, that's ok with me. Also comments!! It must have comments!

Comment: "More social curiosity than actual programming question..."  That makes this off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks @bitmask.  I'll relocate it there.  -3  for asking in the wrong place seems a mite vindictive.

Comment: @bitmask - no it does not.

Comment: @WesMiller Please don't cross post, we can move questions automatically if they are actually more suitable for another site.

Comment: @ChrisF: if it wasn't for the editorial tone ("this is what I think -- tell me why I'm wrong"), this would just be a question about an aspect of programming language design. I'm willing to believe that language design is off-topic for both SO and programmers.SE, because I've seen plenty of questions shot down for plenty of reasons, the daftest of which seem to amount to, "I've never needed to do this at work, so you shouldn't either", and hopefully are isolated errors rather than reflecting SO policy. But IMO language design ought to be on-topic somewhere, perhaps even on both.

Comment: @SteveJessop There probably is a very good Programmers question somewhere in there, if you think you've located it, be bold and edit! And if you do, [either flag for mod attention or drop the question in the Programmers chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135235/when-flagging-a-question-it-should-be-markable-that-it-belongs-to-programmers-se/135239#135239), so we can migrate it.

Comment: @SteveJessop Argh, the question was [cross posted](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/152374/changes-in-language-punctuation).

Answer (score 4):

You're certainly correct concerning the occasional ambiguity between object and function declarations in C++, search for "most vexing parse". However, if you're *invariably* confused then that just means you're not very good at reading C++. You should improve with practice. But anyway C++ is known not to be designed primarily to be easy to read, especially without practice. It has other design priorities. Not everyone shares those priorities, which is why not everyone uses C++.

As for enclosing conditionals in parentheses, you're welcome to write

```
if (foo) { bar; }
```

rather than

```
if(foo) { bar; }
```

in order to create an artificial distinction between the syntax for `if` and the syntax for a function call. C is entirely relaxed about whitespace just so long as the lexer can find the boundaries between tokens, so the rest is style, not language. If you want to know when this relaxation about whitespace started -- I suppose some time during the development of the ALGOL family of languages. I don't know ALGOL58, but that would be one place to check whether it existed or not.

I'm pretty sure that some of your "old ways" languages used parens for grouping in expressions, as well as to enclose function arguments, so the one true meaning you claim for parens as function-call-enclosers never actually existed.

I don't think I've *ever* mistaken `if` in a C or C++ program for a function call, and I think you're expected to learn not to either. If people do strange things with macros that resolve to `if`, no doubt they could confuse me. But then, nobody ever claimed that C-style macros are immune from causing confusion.

If your primary claim is that all languages should punctuate in roughly similar ways, then check out Lisp and Ruby. Hopefully you'll blow a gasket and then get over it ;-)

> I know full well that K&R put the { at the end of the "if" or "for" to
>   save a byte here and there. Can't use that excuse here

That might be why Ritchie put it there, but it's not why I put it there. I put it there mainly to conserve vertical space. That's still limited today: my hard disk may be able to store every line of code I will ever write in a tiny proportion of its capacity, but I still use the full height of my monitor to read code, give or take a bit of screen furniture. I'm pretty sure that the `{`-on-a-line-on-its-own was invented by people who don't like to complicate matters by having more than one function on screen at a time. The extra vertical whitespace neatly prevents this, and also places a tighter limit than more compact styles, on the complexity of a function that will fit on screen.

Python saves another line of vertical space per block, by not bothering with the open-close punctuation at all, although I don't think that's *why* GvR did it that way.

In summary I think my answer is "no", not everybody shares *precisely* your likes and dislikes about code formatting. Or mine. Probably a good thing too.

Comment: "so the one true meaning you claim for parens as function-call-enclosers".  I think you misunderstood.  I alleged that some_word+no space+( denoted functions in Fortran 66 and TRS basic and PL/1.  That just feels natural to an old programmer.

Comment: @Wes: OK, I was exaggerating for comic effect. The serious point is that you don't *have* to write `if(foo)`, it's just that C doesn't constrain where you put whitespace. If "old" turns out to mean "prior to ALGOL58", though, then that really is not a large enough audience to motivate the design of modern languages. Programmers from the 60s are rare enough, programmers from the 50s more so. No offence intended, but we're talking literally more than an epoc in programming terms ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since C++, Java, C# and other modern languages are high-level languages, all these keywords come to make them more understandable and "friendly". They should be as close to our common language as possible.
From time to time the "default" puctuation is changed to make the code look better, more clear and readable. This all is done in order to make programmers' work easier.

Now many frameworks, like Visual Studio (.NET) "correct" your code placing and removing spaces, tabs, etc.

The problem is just getting used to this. This rules change and will keep changing and adopting to new criteria. So the problem of generations is evident here.

BTW, `for` IS a function: it is an iterator. The same for `if` _ it takes a predicate and a function as arguments.

Comment: It's not the framework that does that, it's the IDE.  In any decent IDE, that behavior is configurable.